# I have created a trigger where data cannot be edited on Saturday and Sunday on emp table

Tags: oracle, triggers, oracle11gr1

```
Create or replace trigger trig_error
before insert or update or delete on emp
begin
     if to_char(sysdate,'DY') IN ('SAT','SUN') then
         raise_application_error(-20111,'No changes can be made on tuesday');
     end if;
end;
dbms_output.put_line('no changes can be done on SAT and SUN!!’);
```

But getting the output like this:
Warning: Trigger created with compilation errors.

Comment: Errorneous [mysql] tag removed.

Comment: the `dbms_output` call is outside the trigger body. That's wrong. It's also needless, because the message the user will see is the one from the RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR() call.

Comment: What is it you are expecting from the line `dbms_output.put_line(`...... ?

Comment: So, it if is SAT or SUN, you are telling them they can't do this on TUE.    ?!?!?!?